# Power formula at transformer derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, power, inductance

For the power of an ideal transformer, there is the formula

$U_1\cdot I_1 =U_2\cdot I_2$

which can be derived from energy conservation by saying that there are no energy losses and therefore the electric power of the primary must equal the power delivered to the secondary.

On the other hand there is the equation

$\frac{U_1}{U_2}=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$

for the voltages of an open secondary (no current flow, i.e. **resistance = $\infty$** in the secondary)

and the equation for the currents

$\frac{I_1}{I_2}=\frac{n_2}{n_1}$

which holds if **resistance = 0** in the secondary.

Apparently combining the last two equations I can get the first equation **even though these equations hold for different limiting cases.** (so should per se not be combined)

Is this just by accident? Is there a way to derive the first equation in this way without running into this problem?

Comment: We should pay attention that transformer is 3D installation with distributed electric and magnetic fields  inside and outside. Normally it is working with alternating current , therefore any relation like power and current in windings can't be described by simple algebraic equations but it can be done with differential equations or even with PDE (in modern science).  We can discuss about mean values relations in some ideal cases, but we can't interpolate this relations to an arbitrary case.

Comment: @AlexTrounev So to derive this properly one should write the differential equations for current and voltage, solve them and average the product U*I over a period of oscillation?

Comment: In a case if there is the model describing transformer, then we can solve it. But actually we know PDE only (Maxwell equations). From the other side, we can make some measurements to  define values. I have 3D model of transformer, but it is not general case. Also it is not so simpler problem as it is described in the scholar books.